# How to implement "run command X, fix it if it fails and rerun after the fix" in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

In my playbook, I plan to run a command X, but this command X might fail the first time then I have a fix for that command. If command X fails, then invoke the fix. After the fix, run command X again.

```
    - name: a block with a command that might fail the first time but can be fixed and then rerun that command
    block:
        - name: this task might fail the first time
        command: command X
    
    rescue:
        - name: fix the error caused by command X
        command: fix it!
    
    always:
        - name: run command the second time
        command: command X
```

But i'm not happy with this structure because:

- `always` is run whatever even if command X succeeds.
- command X is very long and I don't like copy and paste the code everywhere.

So do we have a better solution? Any suggestion is appreciated.

[Edit]

I can improve it to:

```
    - name: a block with a command that might fail the first time but can be fixed and then rerun that command
    block:
        - name: this task might fail the first time
        command: command X
    
    rescue:
        - name: fix the error caused by command X
        command: fix it!
        - name: run command the second time
        command: command X
```

But there is still code duplication issue since command X is extremely long and I don't want to copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to run the command a second time when it fails the first time, so it should be part of the `rescue`.

Comment: Thanks. That solves the my first question but do we have a method to avoid copying and pasting issue? In my playbook, command x is extremely long and I don't want to copy and paste it(eye irritating and error-prone).

Comment: Use a variable.

Comment: `Command X` in my post actually stands for several tasks combined together; I use `Command X` just for the purpose of clarity. Using a variable is not an option.

Comment: That is the opposite of clarity. You should have included that information in your question, instead of saying you wanted to run a single command. Move the tasks into a separate file and use include_tasks to include it.